# How to merge two tables with uneven numbers of columns and rows?

Tags: r, join, merge

I am trying to merge two tables based on column names, however one table has less total columns than the other.

For example, here is my first table:

```
df1 = data.frame(Type = c("Example_1","Example_2","Example_3","Example_4","Example_5"), Example_1 = c("NA","NA","NA","NA","NA"), Example_2 = c("NA","NA","NA","NA","NA"), Example_3 = c("NA","NA","NA","NA","NA"), Example_4 = c("NA","NA","NA","NA","NA"), Example_5 = c("NA","NA","NA","NA","NA"))


Type         Example_1  Example_2  Example_3  Example_4  Example_5
Example_1    NA         NA         NA         NA         NA
Example_2    NA         NA         NA         NA         NA
Example_3    NA         NA         NA         NA         NA
Example_4    NA         NA         NA         NA         NA
Example_5    NA         NA         NA         NA         NA
```

Here is my second table:

```
df2 = data.frame(Type = c("Example_1","Example_3","Example_5"), Example_1 = c(0,1,1),Example_3 = c(1,0,1),Example_5 = c(0,0,1))

Type         Example_1  Example_3  Example_5
Example_1    0          1          0
Example_3    1          0          0
Example_5    1          1          1
```

Now I want this to be my final table:

```
Type         Example_1  Example_2  Example_3  Example_4  Example_5
Example_1    0          NAN        1          NAN        0
Example_2    NAN        NAN        NAN        NAN        NAN
Example_3    1          NAN        0          NAN        0
Example_4    NAN        NAN        NAN        NAN        NAN
Example_5    1          NAN        1          NAN        1
```

I want those cells that cross "Example_2" and Example "4" in df1 that are not present in df2 to be filled in as NaNs.

How should I go about doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `match` to get the row index to replace and assign `df2` directly.

```
df1[match(df2$Type, df1$Type), names(df2)] <- df2

#       Type Example_1 Example_2 Example_3 Example_4 Example_5
#1 Example_1         0        NA         1        NA         0
#2 Example_2        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA
#3 Example_3         1        NA         0        NA         0
#4 Example_4        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA
#5 Example_5         1        NA         1        NA         1
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
library(dplyr)
dplyr::left_join(
  df1, df2, 
  by = 'Type', 
  suffix = c('', '_df2')
) %>% 
  mutate(
    Example_1 = ifelse(Example_1=='NA', Example_1_df2, Example_1),
    Example_3 = ifelse(Example_3=='NA', Example_3_df2, Example_3),
    Example_5 = ifelse(Example_5=='NA', Example_5_df2, Example_5),
    Example_1_df2 = NULL, Example_3_df2 = NULL, Example_5_df2 = NULL
  )
```

Also note that if you have `NA` instead of `'NA'` you need to change the mutate job:

```
dplyr::left_join(
  df1, df2, 
  by = 'Type', 
  suffix = c('', '_df2')
) %>% 
  mutate(
    Example_1 = ifelse(is.na(Example_1), Example_1_df2, Example_1),
    Example_3 = ifelse(is.na(Example_3), Example_3_df2, Example_3),
    Example_5 = ifelse(is.na(Example_5), Example_5_df2, Example_5),
    Example_1_df2 = NULL, Example_3_df2 = NULL, Example_5_df2 = NULL
  )
```

This solution may not be ideal if you have many more columns. In fact, if someone else has a solution that generalises to any amount of columns I would like to see it.

Finally you may want to consider adding `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` when generating the dataframes. Hope it works.